# Separate string within bracket where number of bracket varies

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching

This is my first question here and I am messed up with strings. I have some strings in the following format:

```
     I will be here (I may or may not be here) (30-Apr-2013) 
     I am still here (15-Feb-2013)
     I am still here(I may not be here) (I may not be here) (9-Apr-2013)
```

I need to separate the date from the name. As you can see, the number of brackets may vary, but I need the last one only ( rest of the string will be treated as name).

Expected output:

```
1. array( 0=> 'I will be here (I may or may not be here)' , 1=> '30-Apr-2013' )
2. array( 0=> 'I am still here' , 1=> '15-Feb-2013' )
3. array( 0=> ' I am still here(I may not be here) (I may not be here)' , 1=> '9-Apr-2013' )
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @negvoters care to explain what is the problem with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the last occurrence of `(` and then you can use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to get the sub-strings and trim them to the result you want.

---

E.g.

```
/**
 * Return an array with the "name" as the first element and
 * date as the second.
 */
function fun($string)
{
    $datePos = strrpos($string, '(');
    return array (
        trim(substr($string, 0, $datePos - 1)), trim(substr($string, $datePos), ' ()')
    );
}
```

Comment: @czarpino Thanks, I thought I'd let the OP do that :-) By the way, I added a character list to `trim` as that was the reason I mentioned it...

Comment: Ah yes, how embarassing. I just realized.